# Angular2 testing. Promise never resolved inside TestBed.compileComponents

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, testing, promise

I am currently writing a test module for a module within my Angular2 component which uses the templateUrl property and therefore requires the TestBed.compileComponents async call to be made to compile before testing.

The problem I am having is that anything inside the promise callback (then) function does not run at all... As if the promise is not resolving.

Here is my code.

The module:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'categories-component',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/catalog/categories/categories-dashboard.html',
    moduleId: module.id
})

export class CategoriesComponent {
    title: 'Categories;
}
```

HTML template:

```
<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
```

And the testing module:

```
import {TestBed, ComponentFixture, ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, async} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { CategoriesComponent } from "../../../../components/catalog/categories/CategoriesComponent";
import { DebugElement } from "@angular/core";

let comp:    CategoriesComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CategoriesComponent>;
let de:      DebugElement;
let el:      HTMLElement;

describe('CategoriesComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ CategoriesComponent ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ComponentFixtureAutoDetect, useValue: true }
            ]
        });
    });

    it('should display original title', () => {
        TestBed.compileComponents()
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CategoriesComponent);

                comp = fixture.componentInstance; // BannerComponent test instance

                // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
                de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
                el = de.nativeElement;

                expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.title);
            });

});
```

});

As you can see, inside my test I call compileComponents to compile the testing module asynchronously then inside the callback I create the fixture and instance of the test component. None of this ever gets run and I have added breakpoints inside this which never fire.

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the test is synchronous

```
it('...', () => {
})
```

The callback here executes and the test is complete *right after* the callback function executes.

But the problem is you have all you code in an asynchronous callback

```
it('...', () => {
  TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
    // asynchronous
    // code not executed
  })
})
```

So the asynchronous code never gets executed before the test completes.

This can be handled in a couple of ways. You can use the native jasmine `done` callback

```
it('...', (done) => {
  TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
    /// do stuff

    done();
  })
})
```

Here, jasmine passed you a callback function. It is you job to call it when all your asynchronous stuff is done.

The other way, is the use the Angular `async`.

```
import { async } from '@anguar/core/testing';

it('...', async(() => {
  TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {

  })
}))
```

What this does is wrap the test in a test zone, which keeps track of all the asynchronous tasks, and completes the test *after* all asynchronous tasks have complete. In a jasmine environment, the test zone will actually call the jasmine `done` callback, after the async tasks are complete.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did think this was the case but when I have used wither of those solutions I get the following error. Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: I don't know. I've seen that error a few of times. I can't remember what the problem was. Have you googled the error (in relation to Angular 2 and karma)?

Comment: Try and move the template to the `@Component.template` and get rid of the `templateUrl` and don't call the `compileComponents`. See if it works. If it works, then it's a problem with the `compileComponents`. Not sure what would cause it though. At least if you narrow down the problem to this, it will narrow your search

Comment: Great. I will keep trying. At least I know by your answer that I was correct in what I was attempting with the async() function so thanks for your help.